# PLSQL package installation

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Anybody here knows how to install a PLSQL package in Oracle 11g?

I am trying to use these two packages:

1. DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN
2. DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_UTILITY

I am using Oracle Application Express and so far SQL is not able to identify these.

Thank you.

Comment: may be you people should reply instead of giving -1s.. :/

Comment: Oracle APEX, or Oracle 11g Express Edition? Which user are you trying to execute the packages as, and what errors do you get? It's probably a permission problem rather than an installation problem; permission would have to be granted explicitly for both of those I believe - if everyone had access they wouldn't add much security to the platform.

Comment: yes its 11g express edition , i haven't encountered any error yet , right know i don't know how to install them in my database, and account type is workspace administrator,

Comment: the problem is i am not able to request POST method on my database from my mobile application, for that purpose i have to make Access control list (ACL) to grant the host privileges.. i m stuck here , very bad :(

Comment: then why would they make RESTful services in that? if i am not able to use them ? dosn't make sense..

Comment: that was the default role i was given (workspace administrator) when they gave me the service with the default schema..

Comment: i went to oracle cloud.oracle.com , requested database as a service and then i was given the link to the service which i am currently using, these are its specs:
 
Managed Schema
One database schema with an Oracle 11g database,
Editions:
Enterprise Edition,
Access:
Browser based access to database schema using Application Express or from Java or from RESTful web services - no SQL*Net access

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Owner, Object_Type, Object_Name FROM DBA_Objects_AE
     WHERE Owner IN (
       'SYS', 'OUTLN', 'SYSTEM', 'CTXSYS', 'DBSNMP',
       'LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ORDSYS',
       'ORDPLUGINS', 'OEM_MONITOR', 'WKSYS', 'WKPROXY',
       'WK_TEST', 'WKUSER', 'MDSYS', 'LBACSYS', 'DMSYS',
       'WMSYS', 'OLAPDBA', 'OLAPSVR', 'OLAP_USER',
       'OLAPSYS', 'EXFSYS', 'SYSMAN', 'MDDATA',
       'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA', 'XDB', 'ODM')
     AND Object_Type IN ('PACKAGE', 'TYPE')
     ORDER BY Owner, Object_Type, Object_Name

Comment: the above query was in oracle documentation to check which packages are installed , but the result was no such table exists

Comment: i was by default made workspace administrator , then how could i change my role?

Comment: so i am right that this is due to the host previleges i am not able to request POST method ?

Comment: help me here plzzzzzzzzzzzzzz :(

Comment: I don't know why you can't POST or if you need ACLs, I'm not familiar with your setup, and you haven't shown any code or errors. I don't even know which documentation you're referring to. Maybe you'd get more help if you put some effort into your question. You could query `all_objects_ae` instead  of `dba_objects_ae` to see if the packages are visible, or you could try executing them. If you can't see them and you don't have any other access you probably need to talk to Oracle, assuming you get support with your cloud service.

Comment: the GET request went good, i was able to get the response but in case of post it responded with "METHOD not allowed", then i did some googling and found a forum which led me to this documnetation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/sec_admin_ssl.htm#autoId8 ,, plz have a look at it..

Comment: there it states "By default, the ability to interact with network services is disabled in Oracle Database 11g. Therefore, if you are running Oracle Application Express with Oracle Database 11g, you must use the new DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN package to grant connect privileges to any host for the APEX_040100 database user. Failing to grant these privileges results in issues with:

Using Web services in Oracle Application Express.
"

Comment: did this add some clarification ?

Comment: Please add information and clarification to the question, not as comments. But you're jumping to ACLs without knowing what's already configured, it seems. Where have you seen that POST is blocked by an ACL but GET is allowed? That documentation seems to be about outgoing connections from APEX, not incoming, but I might be wrong. Really not my area.

Comment: yes i would but right now i am refereeing to you ,

Comment: i read about that in database security , it didn't said exactly that post is not allowed , but as POST maps to insertion and its data manipulation so may be its not allowed.. ???

Comment: plz have a look at this too :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460650/posting-data-on-cloud-using-http-post-method

Answer (score 0):

## Installing PLSQL packages for DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN

You can check whether they exist first, run this as user sys:

```
select *
from   dba_objects
where  name = ...
```

If they don't exist on Oracle RDBMS (I don't know whether maybe express edition excludes them, but that seems illogical), your database is not installed well. The easiest way is to re-install the database. In that case you don't need to replace the software, only create a new database.

The advanced way is to reinstall parts of the data dictionary. If you have never done it before, you can assume that the database will end up corrupt. You can try for instance executing ?/dbs/catqm.sql.

Replace ? by the path where ORACLE_HOME lives and then rdbms/admin. Such as $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin on Linux. Remember to close the database for other users.

## Maintaining ACL

The extra comments led to the conclusion that ACL are missing. This is the approach I use to maintain them in a package. Please be careful, even 11.2.0.3 has a bad habit of often crashing the session of the connected user on ACL maintenance despite preventive measures.

**Warning! This script allows access to all ports between 1 and 32767. You probably want to restrict this to applicable ports for your application. For ease of use I've pasted it here for all 32K ports.**

**Warning 2! Maintenance of ACL can be non-trivial and can lead to security risks (which we gracefully accepted upto release 11 of Oracle :-). Involve your sysadmin or networkadmin in case of doubt.**

```
--
-- When ORA-24247 errors continue despite creation of a network ACL,
-- first remove the ACL fully as user SYS using:
--
-- begin
--   dbms_network_acl_admin.drop_acl('/sys/acls/invantive-producer.xml');
-- end;
--
-- This occurs incidentally on Oracle 11g R1.
--
prompt Create Access Control Lists.

declare
  l_principal     varchar2(30) := upper('&&itgen_user_owner_login');
  l_acl           varchar2(300);
  l_acl_full_path varchar2(300);
  l_dummy         pls_integer;
  --
  -- To temporary disable this code, sometimes it causes installation
  -- issues.
  --
  l_skip_acl_maintenance boolean := false;
  --
  -- To temporarily disable granting the ACL access.
  --
  l_skip_acl_grants boolean := false;
begin
  l_acl := 'invantive-producer.xml';
  l_acl_full_path := '/sys/acls/' || l_acl;
  --
  if not l_skip_acl_maintenance
  then
    --
    -- Drop superfluous network ACLs for users and roles that no longer exist.
    --
    -- Dropping network ACLs is tricky. Queries on the view dba_network_acls
    -- often lead to ORA-600. This query seems to work reliable on Oracle 11g R1.
    --
    -- First delete all ACL privileges for which no ACL exists.
    -- During this, we will ignore problems.
    --
    for r in
    ( select nae.acl
      ,      nae.principal
      from   dba_network_acl_privileges nae
      where  nae.principal 
             not in 
             ( select usr.username 
               from   dba_users usr
               union all 
               select rle.role 
               from   dba_roles rle
             )
    )
    loop
      begin
        dbms_network_acl_admin.delete_privilege
        ( r.acl
        , r.principal
        );
        dbms_output.put_line('Dropped superfluous ACL ' || r.acl || '  for ' || r.principal || '.');
      exception
        when others
        then
          dbms_output.put_line('Ignoring error ' || sqlerrm);
      end;
    end loop;
    --
    -- Then try another time, not ignoring problems.
    --
    for r in
    ( select nae.acl
      ,      nae.principal
      from   dba_network_acl_privileges nae
      where  nae.principal 
             not in 
             ( select usr.username 
               from   dba_users usr
               union all 
               select rle.role 
               from   dba_roles rle
             )
    )
    loop
      dbms_network_acl_admin.delete_privilege
      ( r.acl
      , r.principal
      );
      dbms_output.put_line('Dropped superfluous ACL ' || r.acl || '  for ' || r.principal || '.');
    end loop;
    --
    -- Now create new network ACL when it does not yet exist.
    --
    begin
      select 1
      into   l_dummy
      from   resource_view rvw
      where  rvw.any_path = l_acl_full_path
      ;
      dbms_output.put_line('ACL ' || l_acl || ' already present. No action.');
    exception
      when no_data_found
      then
        dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl
        ( acl             => l_acl
        , description     => 'Normal Access by Invantive Producer'
        , principal       => 'SYS'
        , is_grant        => true
        , privilege       => 'connect'
        , start_date      => null
        , end_date        => null
        );
        dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl
        ( acl        => l_acl
        , host       => '*'
        , lower_port => 1 /* ATTENTION! You may want to tighten this! */
        , upper_port => 32767 /* ATTENTION! You may want to tighten this! */
        );
        dbms_output.put_line('Created ACL ' || l_acl || ' for port 1 till 32767.');
    end;
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Skipped maintenance of Access Control Lists.');
  end if;
  --
  if not l_skip_acl_grants
  then
    --
    -- Update the privilges for the ACL when not correct.
    --
    for r_usr
    in
    ( select l_principal principal
      from   dual
      union all
      --
      -- Any unspecified Invantive schema.
      --
      -- For SYS, itgen_schemas_r can contain multiple rows.
      --
      select sma_r.name principal
      from   itgen_schemas_r sma_r
    )
    loop
      begin
        select 1
        into   l_dummy
        from   dba_network_acl_privileges nae
        where  nae.acl        = l_acl_full_path
        and    nae.principal  = r_usr.principal
        and    nae.privilege  = 'connect'
        and    nae.is_grant   = 'true'
        and    nae.invert     = 'false'
        and    nae.start_date is null
        and    nae.end_date   is null
        ;
        dbms_output.put_line('Connect privileges already granted to ' || l_principal || '. No action.');
      exception
        when no_data_found
        then
          dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege
          ( acl         => l_acl
          , principal   => l_principal
          , is_grant    => true
          , privilege   => 'connect'
          , start_date  => null
          , end_date    => null
          );
          dbms_output.put_line('Connect privileges granted to ' || l_principal || '.');
      end;
    end loop;
    --
    commit;
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Skipped grants of Access Control Lists.');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: It was established in comments that it's APEX on Enterprise Edition, not Express Edition. The user not having execute permissions on these (powerful) packages seems more likely than them not existing though. They can't see `dba_objects_ae` so probably can't see `dba_objects` either, and probably won't have these packages available. But I'm still not convinced they need them anyway.

Comment: ah, ok, i did not go through all 15 comments once I read `yes its 11g express edition , i haven't encountered any error yet` and the original question `Anybody here knows how to install a PLSQL package in oracle 11g`. Yes, when it is APEX on EE then it is probably missing privileges of an unpriv user. Will add some sample.

Comment: You didn't go through all the comments in detail!? <grin> Yes, I gave up eventually, and deleted most of mine. I'm still waiting for a mod to come along and delete the whole comment thread...

Comment: whousa... even 20 comments after deleting most... I seems that stackoverflow is a real big data platform :-)